# Launch Image Error - Cannot upload ios app created using adobe AIR into ios app store

Tags: ios, air, app-store-connect, application-loader, flash-cc

i have created a simple ios app using adobe flash CC and AIR SDK 16. The app is tested well and working fine in my iphone 5C. And i have successfully filled all the informations in the iTunes Connect. And uploaded all the necessory images like icons and screenshots for 4.7, 5.5, 4, 3.5 inch displays and iPad . But when i try to upload the '.ipa' using the application loader it gives me the error

ERROR ITMS-90096: "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - New iPhone apps and app updates submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5 and must include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately following the  portion of the launch image's filename. Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images by reviewing the 'iOS Human Interface Guidelines' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5' and the 'iOS App Programming Guide' at 'https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW12'."


i do not know what does it means. Can some one please help me

thanks in advance.

Comment: It means that your application does not have a launch image for each of the required screen sizes.

Comment: i am sorry, how/where should i add it?

Comment: I am not familiar with Flash, but I would guess that there's somewhere that you're allowed to specify a launch image or a splash screen.

Comment: There's an "icons" tab in the publish settings.  It adds the icons for the given dimensions.  If there's a dimension you need that's not listed, you can edit the xml file by hand and set Flash to not overwrite it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically using Flash Pro CC...

Click the Publish Settings button in the Publish panel.

Then click the wrench button next to the Target dropdown menu.

Click the General Tab, then the + button for Included files:

Browse to and select your iPhone 5 Default image (which must be named correctly) Here's a handy list of image names:

http://blog.tomasmahrik.com/list-of-properties-sizes-for-application-icons-launch-images-screenshots-video-previews-for-ios-air-apps/

Comment: thank you friends. Its worked. I added the image '640×1136 px Default-568h@2x.png' in the general tab

Comment: You, my friend, deserve literally every upvote ever for this answer. Have been struggling with this issue for a month, and this is the first version I've found that explains how to do it specifically in Flash CC. Only found this after searching for an unrelated thing.

Comment: Include the launch images in the top-most level of your source.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1891346